# Issue with the inline shell commands on packer

Tags: docker, packer

I have been trying to use the following command in packer

```
{
     "inline" : [
        "sudo docker images",
        "sudo docker image list --format \"{{.Tag}}\"",
     ],
     "type" : "shell"
  }
```

The `docker images` command works as expected, prints out the repo, version, etc..., but the second command prints out `<no value>`, using the same command inside a terminal seems to be fine. Not quite sure why this is happening, any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Docker and Packer use the same templating engine which is probably causing Packer to try and interpolate the variable `Tag`, which presumably you dont have defined/set.

You can try double escaping the braces, but based on [this GH comment](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9125#issuecomment-620110800), that may or may not work.

```
{
     "inline" : [
        "sudo docker images",
        "sudo docker image list --format \"\\{\\{.Tag\\}\\}\"",
     ],
     "type" : "shell"
}
```

However, it may be easier just to switch from `inline` to `script`

https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/shell#script